# Mechanics of plotting a linear model (lm) object in R?

Tags: r, plot, visualization, linear-regression, lm

Example:

```
x <- c(1,2,5,6)
y <- c(3,5,2,9)
m <- lm(y ~ x)
plot(m)
```

plot(m) will spit out a series of plots. My question is, how do I know what plots it will spit out? How does Paul Teetor's book know to write `plot(m, which=1)` to select the residuals plot? `ls.str(m)` appears useless here.

My guess is that the lm class has some kind of interface defined for the `plot()` function, but I have no idea how to get any information about how that works or what plots are available (aside from just typing `plot(m)` and writing down what the black box spits out).

Comment: `?plot.lm` should help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned "the `lm` class has some kind of interface defined for the `plot()` function". In fact, this is a S3 mechanism in R, which follows "method.class" naming conventions. Here, the method is `plot` and the class is `lm`. You don't have to type `plot.lm` in order to get these plots. When you call `plot`, R will first examine the class type of the first argument, and fount it (`m` in this case) to be of class `lm`; then R automatically calls the `plot.lm` function.

For the `plot` method, you can see that it applies to more classes by typing `methods(plot)` in R:

```
 [1] plot.acf*           plot.data.frame*    plot.decomposed.ts* plot.default        plot.dendrogram*   
 [6] plot.density        plot.ecdf           plot.factor*        plot.formula*       plot.function      
[11] plot.gofm*          plot.gofv*          plot.hap.score*     plot.hclust*        plot.histogram*    
[16] plot.HoltWinters*   plot.isoreg*        plot.lm             plot.md             plot.medpolish*    
[21] plot.mlm            plot.ppr*           plot.prcomp*        plot.princomp*      plot.profile.nls*  
[26] plot.spec           plot.spline*        plot.stepfun        plot.stl*           plot.table*        
[31] plot.ts             plot.tskernel*      plot.TukeyHSD       plot.xyVector*     

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

You see `plot.lm` is one of them. To learn any one of these, you may use `fix(plot.lm)`. Then you will notice at the first lines:

```
caption = list("Residuals vs Fitted", 
    "Normal Q-Q", "Scale-Location", "Cook's distance", "Residuals vs Leverage", 
    expression("Cook's dist vs Leverage  " * h[ii]/(1 - h[ii])))
```

Obviously you'll know which plots are constructed when you call `plot` on an object of class `lm` :) Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

This page

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/plot.lm.html

explains what the 6 plots are.

The first is residuals, which corresponds to `which=1` from your example. Here is a quote from that page:

`Six plots (selectable by which) are currently available: a plot of residuals against fitted values, a Scale-Location plot of sqrt(| residuals |) against fitted values, a Normal Q-Q plot, a plot of Cook's distances versus row labels, a plot of residuals against leverages, and a plot of Cook's distances against leverage/(1-leverage). By default, the first three and 5 are provided.`

I hope that webpage is a step in the right direction for you.